# Do I need to use revalidate key in getStaticProps Next.JS for lists in page?

Tags: reactjs, static, next.js, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

I'm making static e-commerce app with Next.JS.

I have products directory with `index.js` and `[id].js` files. Do I need to use `revalidate: someTime` in `products/index.js` file which returns list of all products for keeping list up to date? Or it's feature only for product individual pages (`[id].js`)?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: If you want the list of products to be updated when adding a new product you'll want to use `revalidate` in `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use revalidate with getStaticProps data fetching method like this :

```
export const getStaticProps = () => {
  return {
     props : {
      // data  
     } , 
     revalidate : 1
  }
}
```